# using a maybe and just for more then 3 variables

Tags: haskell, syntax, ghc

Hi I can't figure this out myself and i also couldn't find an example online

I'm trying to use a maybe or a guard and the examples i found have just two variables,
when i edit or follow the examples with more then two i get an error heres what i am trying to do

```
--maybe example
    Fun :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Maybe Double
    Fun a b c
        | a >= -1.0 || a <= 1.0 || b >= -1.0 || b <=1.0 || c /=0 || c >= -1.0 = Nothing
        | otherwise = Just max(  ((c^ (-c)) +   (a^(-c)-1.0)  ^   (a+ (-1.0/a)))     0.0)
```

error with gchi

```
 The function `Just' is applied to two arguments,
    but its type `a0 -> Maybe a0' has only one
```

while hlint gives

```
No suggestions
```

trying to use a guard instead i get a different error

```
--guard example
    Fun :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Maybe Double
    Fun a b c
        | a >= -1.0 || a <= 1.0 || b >= -1.0 || b <=1.0 || c /=0 || c >= -1.0 = error "Value out of range "
        | otherwise = max(  ((c^ (-c)) +   (a^(-c)-1.0)  ^   (a+ (-1.0/a)))     0.0)
```

and heres ghc and hlints errors

```
  test.hs:10:1:
        Invalid type signature: Fun :: Double
                                       -> Double -> Double -> Maybe Double
        Should be of form <variable> :: <type>
    $ hlint test.hs
 Error message:
  Left-hand side of type signature is not a variable: Fun
Code:
    Fun :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Maybe Double
  > Fun a b c
```

Comment: `Fun` should be a function, `fun`, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must write functions with a lower-case letter. This means writing this:

```
fun :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Maybe Double
fun a b c ...
```

Functions can never start with upper-case letters, since upper-case identifiers are reserved for modules (`Data.List` for example) and type constructors and data constructors (like `Int` or `Maybe` or `Just`) and some other things.

You also have an issue with the application of the `Just` constructor. If you write this:

```
Just max(something)
```

... it means the same thing as:

```
Just max something
```

i.e. you are giving `Just` two arguments. You need to fix this by adjusting your parens:

```
Just (max something)
```

Answer (score 3):

Syntax errors, mostly:

```
f :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Maybe Double
f a b c
    |  a >= -1
    || a <=  1
    || b >= -1
    || b <=  1
    || c /=  0
    || c >= -1
     = Nothing

    | otherwise
     = Just $ max ((c ** (-c)) + (a ** (-c)-1) ** (a+ (-1/a))) 0
```

Note the use of the more generally-typed exponention operator, `(**)`, and `$` to avoid parens in the `Just` wrapper over `max`.